# Leave FXML files in /src/main/java

Tags: java, maven

Whenever I put FXML files into the `/src/main/java` catalog, it seems like they aren't being included into the final OSGi jar during compilation. I suppose Maven removes them from there because it thinks that FXML files should only reside in the `/src/main/resouces` catalog. Is there a way to stop Maven from doing this (*i.e.* just leave them there)?

**EDIT 1**
The only solution I have found for now is:

```
<build>
<plugins>
....
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
             <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/java</directory>
               <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>           
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin> 
</plugins>
</build>
```

However, as far I understand, there is another, shorter way of achieving this, *i.e.* without the use of additional plugins, in the `<build>...</build>` node. How do I use the shorter method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by default `src/main/resources` is for resource files.
You can use [maven resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) plugin to override this behavior.

Here's an example. In your `pom.xml`

```
...
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <targetPath>com/company/projectname</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/java/com/company/projectname</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

where `<directory>` is the source package which includes resource files(in your case xml files) and `<targetPath>` is the target where you want the resources to reside. You can omit `<targetPath>` if you are ok with having these resources in the root path of the jar.

Comment: Could you provide an example how to include all fxml files?